# Struggling to scrape a telegram public channel with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, for-loop, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, telegram

I'm practicing web **scraping** with BeautifulSoup but I struggle to finish printing a dictionary including the items I've **scraped**

The web targeted can be any telegram public channel (web version) and I pretend to collect and add as part of the dictionary the text message, timestamp, views and image url (if exist attached to the post).

I've inspected the code for the 4 elements but the one related to the image url has no class or span, so I've ended **scraping** them it via regex. The other 3 elements are easily retrievable.

Let's go by parts:

Importing modules

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re
```

Function to get the images url from the public channel

```
def pictures(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
    link = str(soup.find_all('a', class_ = 'tgme_widget_message_photo_wrap')) #converted to str in order to be able to apply regex
    image_url = re.findall(r"https://cdn4.*.*.jpg", link)
    return image_url
```

Soup to get the text message, timestamp and views

```
picture_list = pictures(url)
url = "https://t.me/s/computer_science_and_programming"

channel = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(channel, 'lxml')
tgpost = soup.find_all('div', class_ ='tgme_widget_message')
full_message = {}
for content in tgpost:
    full_message['views'] = content.find('span', class_ = 'tgme_widget_message_views').text
    full_message['timestamp'] = content.find('time', class_ = 'time').text
    full_message['text'] = content.find('div', class_ = 'tgme_widget_message_text').text
    print(full_message)
```

I would really appreciate if someone can help me, I'm new to Python and I don't know how I could do it to

1. Check if the post contains an image and if so, add it to the dictionary
2. Print the dictionary including image_url as key and the url as value for each post.

Thank you very much

Comment: “Scrapping”? The correct term is __scraping__ (and __scrape__, __scraped__, __scraper__)

Comment: Hi Barny, thanks for the correction. I'm not a native English speaker and I use to have some typos when I write. 

Regarding the question itself... do you have an answer that I could try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want something like this.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, re

url = "https://t.me/s/computer_science_and_programming"

channel = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(channel, 'lxml')
tgpost = soup.find_all('div', class_ ='tgme_widget_message')
full_message = {}

for content in tgpost:
    full_message['views'] = content.find('span', class_ = 'tgme_widget_message_views').text
    full_message['timestamp'] = content.find('time', class_ = 'time').text
    full_message['text'] = content.find('div', class_ = 'tgme_widget_message_text').text

    if content.find('a', class_ = 'tgme_widget_message_photo_wrap') != None :
        link = str(content.find('a', class_ = 'tgme_widget_message_photo_wrap'))
        full_message['url_image'] = re.findall(r"https://cdn4.*.*.jpg", link)[0]
    elif 'url_image' in full_message:
        full_message.pop('url_image')

    print(full_message)
```

Comment: Hi Arlene, thanks a lot for taking the time to review and bring a possible answer to my problem. Unfortunately I cannot make it work as you propose. 

The 1st issue I find is that I cannot retrieve the images url with the findall method if they're not converted to strings. And even if I do str() for the 3 calls related inside the if block, I don't get what I'm looking for.

Comment: I've already corrected the code. I think it should work now.

Comment: Lovely, Arlene! Thanks again for helping me with this. 

You're getting closer to the solution but you have the issue than I got in some of my previous tests. 

With your current code, it happens that you always create an image_url link for all posts, even for those that they don't have a picture

Comment: Adding the last condition should solve the issue

Comment: Absolutely brilliant! Many thanks young boy and congratulations! I've tried for days and couldn't make it work!